# How to make dynamic form action address in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a search form on my site, and it looks like this:

```
<form action="/search/results">
<input type="text" name="keyword">
<button type="submit">  // etc...
</form>
```

It gets me into `mysite.com/search/results/` page where I process post parameters.
Of course, I can use the **GET** method, and then it will be

```
/search/results?keyword="some_keyword",
```

but is it possible to make the result page URL look like

```
mysite.com/search/results/keyword
```

Comment: yeah, I know -> but my problem is how to make form redirects me into this addres?

Comment: @Yan I think Pawel is asking how to make a friendly URL, not how to pass extra info. I haven't done much at all with it, but I am pretty sure this is asking about htaccess rewriting based on get data.

Comment: I want it to get me into /search/results/keyword after pressing submit button : )

Comment: is is ONLY the keyword that should be passed this way, or any other form data as well?

Comment: What's the difference? I have a two more fields to pass : )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use jQuery

```
$('#myform').submit(function(){
    $(this).attr('action', $(this).attr('action') + "/" + $(this).find(input[name="keyword"]).val());
});
```

Another possibility is to make a proxy method in your controller, it's useful if you want to have all your post values in the url:

```
public function post_proxy() {
    $seg1 = $this->input->post('keyword');
    $seg2 = $this->input->post('keyword2');
    $seg3 = $this->input->post('keyword3');

    redirect('my_method/'.$seg1.'/'.$seg2.'/'.seg3);
}
```

In that case I would use arrays in post data to simplify code:

```
<input type="text" name="kw[1]">
<input type="text" name="kw[2]">
<input type="text" name="kw[3]">

$segment_array = $this->input->post('kw');
$segments = implode("/", $segment_array);
redirect('my_method'.$segments);
```

Comment: I like the post_proxy solution : )