# Passing info via URL using form_input?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to call this 'search' method using form_input:

```
-- controller
function search($item_to_search, $page_to_display)
{
    //do this and that
}

-- view
<?php
    echo form_open("admin/admin_product_c/search/[words come here]/0"); <-- no clue what to do here..
    echo form_input('search_data', 'Type the words to search');
    //submit button here
?>
```

Is there a way to fill out and complete the form_open when clicking the submit button so that I can pass values via URL?  I'd like to avoid using Session / POST in this case if possible because keeping things in one format really helps me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my answer here:

[How to make dynamic form action address in codeigniter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12070107/how-to-make-dynamic-form-action-address-in-codeigniter/12070284#12070284)

There are two solutions you can choose from - with JavaScript or without, I think the second one fits you.

Comment: Yup, I chose the second one :) Thx