# Add search query to URL in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make dynamic form action address in codeigniter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12070107/how-to-make-dynamic-form-action-address-in-codeigniter)

I have the following that creates a form with an input field for entering search terms. I need to be able to type the search terms into that field, and upon clicking the submit button, it needs to go to a URL in the format of `site.com/search/search+terms`

Basically, I need GET but formatted differently. How can I do this?

```
<?php echo form_open('search', array('id' => 'site-search', 'class' => 'form-search pull-right')); ?>
    <div class="input-append">
        <input type="text" class="input-medium search-query" id="site-search-field" placeholder="Search">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-inverse" id="site-search-submit"><i class="icon-chevron-right icon-white"></i></button>
    </div>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my answer here: [How to make dynamic form action address in codeigniter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12070107/how-to-make-dynamic-form-action-address-in-codeigniter/12070284#12070284)

What you need is a controller method that accepts POST data and uses `redirect()` with arguments from POST in it.

Comment: That would work, but I was hoping to do this without using JavaScript

Comment: Please read the post I've linked. I have suggested two methods there, one with JS, the other without, by the way, in my answer here I have mentioned the one without JS.