# Can't remove index.php, custom route not working

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, wampserver

I know this question is more appropriate for Server Fault but unfortunately I was banned for poor quality questions (I was down voted on 2-3 questions I asked.) So the next best place to ask these questions are here.

I have two problems related to CodeIgniter routing.

The first problem is that I can't seem to get rid of `index.php` in the url. I followed the [instructions on how to remove it](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/wiki/Removing-index.php-in-codeigniter-xampp-for-windows). I have the following mod rewrite code in my .htaccess file (see below) at the root of my WAMP server (CI is located at the root, not in its own folder). I have uncommented this line in `httpd.conf` file `LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so`. I deleted `index.php` from `$config['index_page'] = "index.php";`. And I restarted all WAMP services.

My second problem is that I have a controller called `search` and a method called `index`. I would like to change the resultant URL from `http://localhost/index.php/search/index` to `http://localhost/search/whatever_im_searching_for`. I tried the following custom route in my routes.php file but it did not work: `$route['search/(.*)'] = "search/$1";`

```
RewriteEngine On

# Put your installation directory here:
# If your URL is www.example.com/, use /
# If your URL is www.example.com/site_folder/, use /site_folder/

RewriteBase /

# Do not enable rewriting for files or directories that exist
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# For reuests that are not actual files or directories,
# Rewrite to index.php/URL
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [PT,L]
```

I am struggling to understand the code in `.htaccess` and on how to use CI's custom routing. Any assistance will be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

---

**EDIT 1**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Edit your htaccess like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^LoginTut.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|table-images|js|robots\.txt|css|captcha)

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L]
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
 ErrorDocument 404 index.php
</IfModule>
```

To have your searchterms in the url you can look at this:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12070284/1379394

Comment: +1 Thank you for your reply Kees. Unfortunately, i'm still getting the `index.php` in my url. I pasted your code in the .htaccess file in my root and restarted all WAMP services. I find this is very strange! I've edited my question to include a screen shot of my www directory. What else can I try?

Comment: My uri_protocol in config.php is set to `$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';` Does this have anything to do with my problem?

Comment: I have another .htaccess file inside the application directory that has `Deny from all`

Comment: uri_protocol is set to `AUTO` by default. So that has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 1):

Second problem:

```
$route['search/(:any)'] = "search/index/$1";
```

Comment: +1 Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately, it did not work even after I restarted WAMP services. I don't understand why none of these options are working. It used to work up to recently. I'm feel there is a setting in the httpd file that is preventing my issues from being resolved. I'm rereading http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/htaccess.html

Answer (score 1):

Check Apache's default config file. On WAMP it's probably in

```
<WAMPSERVER_HOME>\bin\apache\Apache2.2.xx\conf
```

If it looks like this:

```
    DocumentRoot /var/www
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>
```

then change both:

```
AllowOverride None
```

to:

```
AllowOverride All
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I fixed only by write in my `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

and it's  working perfectly.